# time series forecasting with a small dataset(fewer observations) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have around a small dataset(9 data points). So I think its hard to apply the Arima or sarima model(due to the **fewer observations**).  How could i forecast for next 4 weeks.

Line chart:

[image]

Data:

```
{'Week': {0: Timestamp('2022-03-07 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-03-14 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-03-21 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-03-28 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-04-04 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2022-04-11 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2022-04-18 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2022-04-25 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2022-05-02 00:00:00')},
 'Runs': {0: 191,
  1: 190,
  2: 198,
  3: 245,
  4: 179,
  5: 219,
  6: 195,
  7: 159,
  8: 177}}
```

Take look and please give me **some suggestions that I can try** !!!

Comment: Stats stackexchange is the appropriate forum to ask modeling questions, see e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135061/best-method-for-short-time-series

Comment: Well, you can't really identify trends with a tiny population like that.  You can certainly do linear regression and create a simple trend line.  With that data, the trend line is basically a horizontal line, so maybe an average is enough.